# Storing cookies as json but stored in wrong format

Tags: javascript, php, json

I've got a problem with my cookies, and I can not figured out what is the problem there.

Here is my example `test.php`

```
$defaultActions = array(
                '1' => '0',
                '2' => '0',
                '3' => '0',
                '4' => '0',
                '5' => '0',
                '6' => '0',
                '7' => '0',
                '8' => '0',
                '9' => '0',
                '10' => '0'
            );
$json_str = json_encode($defaultActions); 
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'])) {
    $cookies = explode(';', $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']);
    foreach($cookies as $cookie) {
        $parts = explode('=', $cookie);
        $name = trim($parts[0]);
        setcookie($name, '', time()-1000);
        setcookie($name, '', time()-1000, '/');
    }
}

setcookie("test", urldecode ($json_str), false,"/",false); 

?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function getCookie(name) {
        var value = "; " + document.cookie;
        var parts = value.split("; " + name + "=");
        if (parts.length == 2)
            return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
    } 

    console.log(getCookie('test'));

</script>
```

The problem is that the cookie will be stored like this:

```
%7B%221%22%3A%220%22%2C%222%22%3A%220%22%2C%223%22%3A%220%22%2C%224%22%3A%220%22%2C%225%22%3A%220%22%2C%226%22%3A%220%22%2C%227%22%3A%220%22%2C%228%22%3A%220%22%2C%229%22%3A%220%22%2C%2210%22%3A%220%22%7D
```

The string in PHP is correct. But when I store it in a cookie, the format has changed like the example above. So I can not read the cookie in JavaScript correctly.

Did anyone has some suggestions?

**The solution**

```
<?php

$defaultActions = array(
                '1' => '0',
                '2' => '0',
                '3' => '0',
                '4' => '0',
                '5' => '0',
                '6' => '0',
                '7' => '0',
                '8' => '0',
                '9' => '0',
                '10' => '0'
            );
$json_str = json_encode($defaultActions); 

//delete all cookies
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'])) {
    $cookies = explode(';', $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']);
    foreach($cookies as $cookie) {
        $parts = explode('=', $cookie);
        $name = trim($parts[0]);
        setcookie($name, '', time()-1000);
        setcookie($name, '', time()-1000, '/');
    }
} 
//setrawcookie("test", $json_str, false,"/",false); 

setcookie("test", $json_str, false,"/",false);

?>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function getCookie(name) {
        var value = "; " + document.cookie;
        var parts = value.split("; " + name + "=");
        if (parts.length == 2)
            return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
    } 

    console.log(decodeURIComponent(getCookie('test')));

</script>
```

Thanks to [@Alex Blex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1110423/alex-blex)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[setcookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) automatically [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)s its value. Using [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) to the parameter wont help, as it does nothing to the json string.

Instead you need to use [setrawcookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setrawcookie.php).  It will send the string as is, so you may need to take extra care of what you are sending.

**UPDATE:**

To keep it simple, it would be advisable to keep cookies encoded, and decode it in javascript:

```
console.log(decodeURIComponent(getCookie('test')));
```

Comment: OK, seems perfect. But I get an error message: Warning: Cookie values cannot contain any of the following ',; \t\r\n\013\014' in test.php on line 27 - So I had to change the format? - Or do you have suggestion?

Comment: That's exactly the case to " take extra care of what you are sending".  See my update.

Comment: Maybe you do not get my problem. The problem is that the json format includes a "," in. So the setrawcookie function said that  "," is not allowed. The only way is to change the format, but I think this is not the right way. There should be a way to get cookies work with json strings. I see your updated answer, but in my opinion it will not clear out my problem the right way. But maybe I get it wrong.

Comment: Have you tried it? `setcookie("test", $json_str, false,"/",false); ` on the serverside and `decodeURIComponent(getCookie('test'))` on the client gives me the exact json string which can be used in `JSON.parse`.

Comment: My fault! - I tried it with setcookieraw. It works. Thanks a lot. Saved me a lot work. There was not enough to find via google about this theme.